# Webpack: --hot or HotModuleReplacementPlugin not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, hot-reload

i am working on a little Isomorphic React App and i want to set the HMR tool with webpack.
I have tried wbpack-dev-server --hot or the HotModuleReplacementPlugin but none of them work...

Here is the webpack.config.js and the package.json.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var fs = require('fs');
let webpack = require('webpack');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

var config = { // la configuration commune pour les 2 modes.
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
  entry: {
    '/bundle-app': ['babel-polyfill','./clientside/indexClient.js'],
    '/components/bundle-components': ['babel-polyfill','./components/App.js','./components/Form.js', './components/objetform/Home.js', './components/objetform/SetDB.js'],
    '/server/bundle-server': ['babel-polyfill','./serverside/server/createserver/app.js','./serverside/server/createserver/indexServer.js','./serverside/server/renderpage/renderFullPage.js','./serverside/server/renderpage/routerPage.js','./serverside/server/request/routerDB.js','./serverside/server/request/routerSetDB.js','./serverside/server/routes/routes.js',],
    '/services/bundle-services': ['./serverside/services/getMongooseData.js','./serverside/services/setMongooseData.js', './serverside/services/models/Employe.js'],
    '/assets/stylesheets/style': './assets/stylesheets/style.css',

  },
  target:'node',
  output: 
  {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'), // path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'), // on crée l'application de sortie dans un dossier "public"
    filename: '[name].js', // les fichier bundle seront dans le chemin qui est le nom des fichiers d'entrées
  },
  module: 
  {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // pour les fichiers de type js et jsx
        loader: 'babel-loader', // on charge babel un transcompileur 
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: 
        {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
        }
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
          use:[
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options:
              {
                publicPath: '../../../build'
              },
            },
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
          ]
      }
    ]
  },  
  plugins: [
    //new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css', chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};

module.exports = (env, argv) =>
{
  if (argv.mode === 'development') // la configuration en plus en mode dévelopement
  {
    devtool = 'eval'

    config.devServer = { // mise en place pour le serveur test
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      inline: true,
      hot: true,
    }

  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') // la configuration en plus en mode production
  {
    devtool = 'source-map'
  }
    return config;
}
```

```
{
  "name": "ssr-react-router-mongoose-isomorphic-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "isomorpic app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:server": "babel ./app/server -d build/server",
    "build:watch:server": "babel ./app/server -d build/server --watch",
    "build:client": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js/  --progress ",
    "build:watch:client": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --hot",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:server && npm run build:client",
    "start": "npm run build:prod && NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server/bundle-server.js",
    "start:dev": "parallelshell \"npm run build:watch:client\" \"nodemon ./build/server/bundle-server.js\" ",
    "start:dev:client": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Rando Mathias",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.6",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

For info, before hot reloadind, i used the **npm** command: **npm run build:client** then **npm run start:dev**.
Also when i save my code the powershell does actually respond but it does not compile the new code or refresh the browser. It does print in the powershell this:

> ‼ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 09c22a67c879a7645c8e Version: webpack 4.44.2 Time:
> 1716ms Built at: 2020-11-03 9:28:33
> Asset       Size                                                        Chunks
> Chunk Names
> /assets/stylesheets/style.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js   1.86 KiB          /assets/stylesheets/style, /assets/stylesheets/style  [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  /assets/stylesheets/style,
> /assets/stylesheets/style
> /assets/stylesheets/style.css   3.18 KiB                                     /assets/stylesheets/style  [emitted]                    /assets/stylesheets/style
> /assets/stylesheets/style.js    102 KiB                                     /assets/stylesheets/style
> [emitted]                    /assets/stylesheets/style
> /bundle-app.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js   11.9 KiB                                      /bundle-app, /bundle-app  [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  /bundle-app, /bundle-app
> /bundle-app.js   3.02 MiB                                                   /bundle-app  [emitted]                    /bundle-app
> /components/bundle-components.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> 11.9 KiB  /components/bundle-components, /components/bundle-components  [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  /components/bundle-components,
> /components/bundle-components
> /components/bundle-components.js   3.02 MiB                                 /components/bundle-components  [emitted]                    /components/bundle-components
> /server/bundle-server.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js   11.9 KiB                  /server/bundle-server, /server/bundle-server  [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]  /server/bundle-server,
> /server/bundle-server
> /server/bundle-server.js   13.3 MiB                                         /server/bundle-server  [emitted]                    /server/bundle-server
> /services/bundle-services.js   8.37 MiB                                     /services/bundle-services  [emitted]                    /services/bundle-services
> 911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.json  152 bytes
> [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] Entrypoint /bundle-app = /bundle-app.js
> /bundle-app.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> /bundle-app.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js Entrypoint
> /components/bundle-components = /components/bundle-components.js
> /components/bundle-components.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> /components/bundle-components.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> Entrypoint /server/bundle-server = /server/bundle-server.js
> /server/bundle-server.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> /server/bundle-server.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js Entrypoint
> /services/bundle-services = /services/bundle-services.js Entrypoint
> /assets/stylesheets/style = /assets/stylesheets/style.css
> /assets/stylesheets/style.js
> /assets/stylesheets/style.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> /assets/stylesheets/style.911d579609fd270f8926.hot-update.js
> [./components/objetform/Home.js] 6.33 KiB {/bundle-app}
> {/components/bundle-components} {/server/bundle-server} [built]
> + 971 hidden modules

I am on **Visual Studio Code**.

Thanks in advance.